# How do I format an array passed to params of an axios get to this specific format: [0].mfr=mfr0&[0].mpn=mpn0&[1].mfr=mfr1&[1].mpn=mpn1

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm making a axios get call to a web api that is looking to have the query string parameters in this specific format which seems uncommon: [0].mfr=mfr0&[0].mpn=mpn0&[1].mfr=mfr1&[1].mpn=mpn1

I've been trying to use the Qs library to stringify the params in the paramsSerializer option.

parts = [{ mfr: "mfr0", mpn: "mpn0" }, { mfr: "mfr1", mpn: "mpn1" }]

```
findParts(parts, token) {
    return axios
      .request({
        url: "https://<serveraddress>/api/v1/parts/findparts",
        method: "get",
        params: parts,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        Vue.notify({
          type: "error",
          title: "Unable to find parts",
          text: "Unable to find parts"
        });
      });
  }
```

result

0={"mfr":"mfr0","mpn":"mpn0"}&1={"mfr":"mfr1","mpn":"mp1"}

```
paramsSerializer: function(params) {
          return qs.stringify(params);
},
```

or

```
paramsSerializer: function(params) {
          return qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: "brackets" });
},
```

or

```
paramsSerializer: function(params) {
          return qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: "indices" });
},
```

result

0[mfr]=mfr0&0[mpn]=mpn0[mfr]=mfr1&1[mpn]=mpn1

```
paramsSerializer: function(params) {
          return qs.stringify(params, { allowDots: true });
},
```

result

0.mfr=mf0&0.mpn=mpn0&1.mfr=mfr1&1.mpn=mpn1

I can create a custom paramsSerializer but I was wonder if there a way to manipulate qs or the passed parts array to get the correct query string results without having to manually create the query string and url encode the values?

Comment: im interested in which backend accepts such weird array notations

Comment: I believe its .net web api hosted in Azure.  The dev said its accepting and IEnumerable.